# Перебор таблицы в цикле

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица Resume(id, title, description), FavoriteResume(id, idCreator, idResume) и User(id, name)

Необходимо написать процедуру которая вернет список всех резюме + информацию о том, какое резюме является избранным для пользователя.

Вот как я начал делать

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetResumes
@idUser int
AS
BEGIN    
//заполняем таблицу result кроме последнего поля
    DECLARE @result table(_id int, _title varchar(50), _description varchar(500), _isFav bit)
    INSERT INTO @result(_id, _title, _description)
    SELECT _Resume._id, _Resume._title, _Resume._description
    FROM _Resume

//находим все id-шники избранных резюме нашего пользователя
    DECLARE @identif table(_id int)
    INSERT INTO @identif
    SELECT _idResume
    FROM _Resume INNER JOIN _FavoriteResume ON _Resume._id = _FavoriteResume._idResume
    WHERE _idUser LIKE @idUser

//Вот тут нужно в таблицу @result в поле isFav внести true
// если id этого резюме лежит в таблице @identif 

    SELECT *
    FROM @result
END
```

[image: Вот такой результат должен быть]

Скажите пожалуйста как правильно это сделать.

Comment: зачем вам две доп. таблицы с инсертами и т.п. Вы судя по всему умете использовать джойны. Просто выведите то что надо, Какой вы еще цикл сюда хотите приделать? один запрос с лефт джойном нужен для вашей задачи и все.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проверять не на чем, но ваш код выборки должен сводиться примерно к этому:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetResumes @idUser int
AS
BEGIN 
    SELECT r.id
         , r.title
         , r.description 
         , (CASE WHEN f.id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS isFav
    FROM resume as r
    LEFT JOIN FavoriteResume AS f ON (
         f.idResume = r.id
         AND f.idCreator = @userId
    )
END
```

вы же фактически создаете табличные переменные и копируете туда содержание своих таблиц, не понятно зачем вы это делаете. Вдобавок `LIKE` к целочисленному полю применять несколько странно. А также не ясно, что за поле `_idUser`

Comment: Гениально и просто) спасибо большое! Именно то, что мне нужно было.

Comment: эээ, я бы сказал, что это основы SQL